# How to auto focus camera on a point in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I want to know is there any built-in feature for auto focus a camera into a point in three.js so that the rest of the environment became relatively blur like something we have in these examples ?

http://alteredqualia.com/xg/examples/animation_physics_level.html
http://alteredqualia.com/xg/examples/animation_physics_ammo.html

The code in XG library that enabled auto focus, is something like this:

```
renderer.dofEnabled = false;
renderer.dofAutofocus = true;
renderer.dofAutofocusPoint.set( 0.5, 0.35 );
renderer.dofFocusDistance = 10;
renderer.dofFocusMaxBlur = 0.2;
```

I don't know about the XG library history but It seems that XG library in above links, is based on three.js but we don't have any camera auto focus or dofEnabled in three.js.

If there is some easy way to do it in three.js, please let me know, if not, any suggestions to know how to implement it is so much appreciated.

I don't know, but It seems that XG library is something private and the code is obfuscated so I can't find out how the focus feature implemented.

Comment: XG is a customized version of threejs, written by alterdqualia. So, its not supported by any authorities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out that, this effect is called "depth of field" (dof) and already implemented by using MeshDepthMaterial and there is an example in threejs website:

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_dof.html